# as.difftime() from string

Tags: r, difftime

The result of the following instruction:

```
as.difftime("5 11:04:36", "%d %H:%M:%S", units =("mins"))
```

is

```
Time difference of -7975.4 mins
```

It seems that this function is calculating the time difference between Sys.Time() and the given value.
I actually need an object to store a time span value extracted from a string (). Am I using the wrong function or is it not the right way of using it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Time *span* requires two date-times. Where is your second date-time?

Comment: @CPak that's the question. The value I want to store is itself a span. The question is just: which R object can store a time span? Does it exist?

Comment: Are `lubridate` classes what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @CPak. I think that replacing some characters with time units, the Duration class is what I was searching for.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Could I ask: why are these classes preferred to a `Date` class?

Comment: @CPak because the value is a time interval. A Date implies useless information (year, month, etc...) that make unclear the data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)

I think you want something like `Duration-class`, `Period-class`, or `Timespan-class`

```
# Duration
dur <- duration(hours = 10, minutes = 6)
# [1] "36360s (~10.1 hours)"

# Period
per <- period(hours = 10, minutes = 6)
# [1] "10H 6M 0S"
```